# single-row subquery returns more than one row in Redshift when I try to use CASE in UPDATE

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use a case statement with sub query in a Update statement  but I am facing an Issue like

> single-row sub query returns more than

Please find my Query which I tried

```
update r_gl.ac
set meeting_cost = case currency_code when 'IND'
                   then amount
                   else round(tgt.amount)
from r_gl.ac tgt 
join
(
    select distinct
        a.frm_cur,
        a.to_cur,
        a.exch_rate
    from b_gl.currncy_conv_dim a  
    join r_gl.ac b
        on (a.frm_cur = 123 and a.to_cur = b.cur_cd  and f_rate = 'ABC') 
    join b_gl.int_fg
        on b.in_s=c.in_s and a.cal_sk = trunc(c.intact_dt_key,-2)
) src
    on tgt.cur_cd=src.to_cur
)
end
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Your `case` has no `end`.  I'm surprised this code runs at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Check the very bottom of the query.

Comment: Actually I have mentioned in last line

Comment: Since you are not using anything from the subquery, you could replace it by a (correlated)`EXISTS()`subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `CASE` expression is missing its `END`.  That aside, I see even bigger problems with your `UPDATE` statement.  Redshift is based on an old version of Postgres, and hence I expect that it would adhere to the same syntax Postgres would use for an update join:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
SET some_column = t2.some_other_column
FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

Applying this syntax to your current query along with the fix for the `CASE` expression leaves us with the following:

```
update r_gl.ac tgt
set meeting_cost = case when currency_code = 'IND'
                   then tgt.amount
                   else round(tgt.amount) end
from
(
    select distinct
        a.frm_cur,
        a.to_cur,
        a.exch_rate
    from b_gl.currncy_conv_dim a  
    inner join r_gl.ac b
        on (a.frm_cur = 123 and a.to_cur = b.cur_cd  and f_rate = 'ABC') 
    inner join b_gl.int_fg
        on b.in_s=c.in_s and a.cal_sk = trunc(c.intact_dt_key,-2)
) src
where tgt.cur_cd = src.to_cur
```

The table to which you are joining `r_gl.ac` has no effect on the data being used to update, but rather would only affect the update by targeting certain rows.  If this be not your intended logic, then you might have to rethink the entire query.

Comment: hi thanks ,  now the query is working but the 1st part of the query   "update r_gl.ac tgt set meeting_cost = case currency_code when 'IND' then amount "  (Condition) is not working when I add the else part. but without else condition  the 1st part of query is working fine

Comment: @user4665655 I think the issue may the syntax of the `CASE` statement you were using.  Try my updated query.